# Need to pull only last date in table that stores change dates SQL / ODBC

Tags: sql, odbc

Hope somebody can help me with this. I'm trying to pull a list of forthcoming titles (I work in publishing) via ODBC/ms query. I want (amongst other things) to show their internal status (approved, prepress etc.). The database stores the change dates for the status'. I seem to be getting one line per status per title. So if the title has changed status 6 times, I will get 6 lines. But I only want to show the latest status...

The date is in BL_PROJECT_TO_STATUS.STATUS_DATE (I've inserted a date criteria beneath, just to make it more visible).

How can this be done? I'm very new to ODBC and would appreciate it a lot.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    BL_PROJECT.EXP_PUB_DATE, BL_PROJECT.EAN, BL_PROJECT.TITEL,
    MEDIATYPE.DESCRIPTION, BL_PROJECT_STATUS.DESCRIPTION
FROM 
    FIRMA1.BL_PROJECT BL_PROJECT, FIRMA1.BL_PROJECT_STATUS BL_PROJECT_STATUS,   
    FIRMA1.BL_PROJECT_TO_STATUS BL_PROJECT_TO_STATUS, FIRMA1.MEDIATYPE MEDIATYPE
WHERE 
    BL_PROJECT.PROJECT_ID = BL_PROJECT_TO_STATUS.PROJECT_ID AND  
    BL_PROJECT_TO_STATUS.STATUS_ID = BL_PROJECT_STATUS.CODE AND 
    BL_PROJECT.MEDIATYPE = MEDIATYPE.ID AND 
    ((BL_PROJECT.PROJECT_TYPE = 2) AND 
     (BL_PROJECT.EXP_PUB_DATE Between SYSDATE AND (SYSDATE+90)) AND 
    (BL_PROJECT_TO_STATUS.STATUS_DATE = {ts '2013-11-20 00:00:00'}))
ORDER BY 
     BL_PROJECT.EXP_PUB_DATE, BL_PROJECT.EAN, BL_PROJECT.TITEL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the general idea.  You can adapt it with your table and field names.

```
select somefields
from sometables
join
(select something, max(datetimefield) maxdt
from table1
where whatever
group by something ) temp on table1.datetimefield = maxdt
etc
```